# Time to zip very large (100G) files

Tags: linux, gzip

I find myself having to compress a number of very large files (80-ish GB), and I am surprised at the (lack of) speed my system is exhibiting. I get about 500 MB / min conversion speed; using `top`, I seem to be using a single CPU at approximately 100%.

I am pretty sure it's not (just) disk access speed, since creating a `tar` file (that's how the 80G file was created) took just a few minutes (maybe 5 or 10), but after more than 2 hours my simple gzip command is still not done.

In summary:

```
tar -cvf myStuff.tar myDir/*
```

Took <5 minutes to create an 87 G tar file

```
gzip myStuff.tar
```

Took two hours and 10 minutes, creating a 55G zip file.

My question: Is this normal? Are there certain options in `gzip` to speed things up? Would it be faster to concatenate the commands and use `tar -cvfz`? I saw reference to `pigz` - [Parallel Implementation of GZip](http://www.zlib.net/pigz/) - but unfortunatly I cannot install software on the machine I am using, so that is not an option for me. See for example [this earlier question](https://superuser.com/questions/438694/compression-of-large-files).

I am intending to try some of these options myself and time them - but it is quite likely that I will not hit "the magic combination" of options.  I am hoping that someone on this site knows the right trick to speed things up.

When I have the results of other trials available I will update this question - but if anyone has a particularly good trick available, I would really appreciate it. Maybe the gzip just takes more processing time than I realized...

**UPDATE**

As promised, I tried the tricks suggsted below: change the amount of compression, and change the destination of the file. I got the following results for a tar that was about 4.1GB:

```
flag    user      system   size    sameDisk
-1     189.77s    13.64s  2.786G     +7.2s 
-2     197.20s    12.88s  2.776G     +3.4s
-3     207.03s    10.49s  2.739G     +1.2s
-4     223.28s    13.73s  2.735G     +0.9s
-5     237.79s     9.28s  2.704G     -0.4s
-6     271.69s    14.56s  2.700G     +1.4s
-7     307.70s    10.97s  2.699G     +0.9s
-8     528.66s    10.51s  2.698G     -6.3s
-9     722.61s    12.24s  2.698G     -4.0s
```

So yes, changing the flag from the default `-6` to the fastest `-1` gives me a 30% speedup, with (for my data) hardly any change to the size of the zip file. Whether I'm using the same disk or another one makes essentially no difference (I would have to run this multiple times to get any statistical significance).

If anyone is interested, I generated these timing benchmarks using the following two scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
# compare compression speeds with different options
sameDisk='./'
otherDisk='/tmp/'
sourceDir='/dirToCompress'
logFile='./timerOutput'
rm $logFile

for i in {1..9}
  do  /usr/bin/time -a --output=timerOutput ./compressWith $sourceDir $i $sameDisk $logFile
  do  /usr/bin/time -a --output=timerOutput ./compressWith $sourceDir $i $otherDisk $logFile
done
```

And the second script (`compressWith`):

```
#!/bin/bash
# use: compressWith sourceDir compressionFlag destinationDisk logFile
echo "compressing $1 to $3 with setting $2" >> $4
tar -c $1 | gzip -$2 > $3test-$2.tar.gz
```

Three things to note:

1. Using `/usr/bin/time` rather than `time`, since the built-in command of `bash` has many fewer options than the GNU command
2. I did not bother using the `--format` option although that would make the log file easier to read
3. I used a script-in-a-script since `time` seemed to operate only on the first command in a piped sequence (so I made it look like a single command...).

With all this learnt, my conclusions are

1. Speed things up with the `-1` flag (accepted answer)
2. Much more time is spend compressing the data than reading from disk
3. Invest in faster compression software (`pigz` seems like a good choice).
4. If you have multiple files to compress you can put each `gzip` command in its own thread and use more of the available CPU (poor man’s `pigz`)

Thanks everyone who helped me learn all this!

Comment: tar -cvf doesn't do any compression so it will be quicker

Comment: @parkydr - Thanks for your comment. I am aware of the reasons why `tar -cvf` is quicker: I added the information to show that my disk access on this system is quite fast, and not limiting the speed of the `gzip`. I understand that I need `tar -cvfz` in order to get both tar and compression. But I'm looking for any tricks I missed to speed up compression.

Comment: @Floris: what kind of data are you trying to compress? side-note: `$> gzip -c myStuff.tar | pv -r -b > myStuff.tar.gz` will show you how fast your machine is compressing the stuff. side-note2: store the result onto a different disc.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  gzip has the --fast option to select the fastest compression

Comment: @Floris as akira mentioned, try outputting to a different disk.  The seeks between read and write operations might be contributing to your problem.  Also, tar -cvfz will do the tar and compression in one step, so it will be faster than separately running tar, then gzip.

Comment: @parkydr : The --fast option is one I didn't know about... it's the very last one in the `man` page, and I didn't read that far (because it's sorted by 'single letter command', which is `-#`). That will teach me to RTFM! This will be the next thing I try!

Comment: @akira - the data is a fairly dense "proprietary format" - there are actually three kinds of files, one of which is hardly compressible while the other two are fairly sparse. Unfortunately there is no simple expression that distinguishes them. Is there a way to "compress just some" files, based on an expression? My machine doesn't appear to have the `pv` command... `uname -r` returns `2.6.18-164.el5` . Pretty sure this is Red Hat.

Comment: @rob - I will try to find another disk to write to, and time the difference. I really appreciate everyone's suggestions and will be sure to update timing benchmarks when my testing is completed.

Comment: @Floris: regarding `pv`: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=pv&srodzaj=3 . aside from that: `proprietary` sounds like `bad compression ratio`. thus i would advise you to less cpu and to compress `just a little bit` (see the answer of @user1291332), flags -1 or -2.

Comment: Note that if a suitable compiler is available on the machine, and the filesystem permissions are not set to prohibit executing binaries from the directories you have access to, you can compile `pigz` and run it from wherever you happened to build it, without installing it. If there is no compiler, you could cross-compile it on another computer, although that's starting to get into more effort than might be worth it. (Depending on just how badly you need this compression to run faster, I guess.)

Comment: I came here because I was interested in what the title promised: 100GB. Then the question was about a file with 80GB which took 2 hours to compress down to 50GB. Then the benchmark speeds you gave us was for something that was 4GB. So, you ended up using -1 ? How long did it take for the 80GB file (or 100GB files), and how much did it compress?

Comment: I'd be interested if gzip experts have a view, but my guess would be that technically the speedup via the fastest compression mode is from it not trying to compress data across the entire file - with very large files, you'd get a giant symbol set and spend a lot of time traversing the target file trying to compress everything. Presumably the fastest mode compresses only a small window (in bytesize) of data at a time and never backtracks to improve the compression on prior windows, allowing it to traverse the entire file just once, more-or-less.

Comment: @stevemidgley your curiosity is more likely to be satisfied if you turn your comment into a well-formulated question (perhaps with a link to this one)... more likely to be seen by someone who can answer it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can change the speed of gzip using `--fast` `--best` or `-#` where # is a number between 1 and 9 (1 is fastest but less compression, 9 is slowest but more compression). By default gzip 
runs at level 6.

Comment: I use 7zip on a Win10 virtual machine. Going from default 5 to the fastest 1 compression the speed went from some 7MB/s to about 48MB/s. The compression ratio went from about 18% to 30%, which is acceptable in my case. The 4 virtual CPUs are pegged at 100%.

Answer (score 52):

The reason tar takes so little time compared to gzip is that there's very little computational overhead in copying your files into a single file (which is what it does). gzip on the otherhand, is actually using compression algorithms to shrink the tar file.

The problem is that gzip is constrained (as you discovered) to a single thread.

Enter [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/), which can use multiple threads to perform the compression. An example of how to use this would be:

```
tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f tar.file dir_to_zip
```

There is a nice succint summary of the --use-compress-program option over on [a sister site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27541309/963438).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and links. I actually mentioned pigz in the question.

Comment: This is the correct answer here..!

Answer (score 5):

> I seem to be using a single CPU at approximately 100%.

That implies there isn't an I/O performance issue but that the compression is only using one thread (which will be the case with gzip).

If you manage to achieve the access/agreement needed to get other tools installed, then 7zip also supports multiple threads to take advantage of multi core CPUs, though I'm not sure if that extends to the gzip format as well as its own.

If you are stuck to using just gzip for the time being and have multiple files to compress, you could try compressing them individually - that way you'll use more of that multi-core CPU by running more than one process in parallel. Be careful not to overdo it though because as soon as you get anywhere near the capacity of your I/O subsystem performance will drop off precipitously (to lower than if you were using one process/thread) as the latency of head movements becomes a significant bottleneck.

Comment: thanks for your input. You gave me an idea (for which you get an upvote): since I have multiple archives to create I can just write the individual commands followed by a `&` - then let the system take care of it from there. Each will run on its own processor, and since I spend far more time on compression than on I/O, it will take the same time to do one as to do all 10 of them. So I get "multi core performance" from an executable that's single threaded...

Answer (score 1):

One can exploit the number of process available as well in pigz which is usually faster performance as shown in the following command

> tar cf - directory to archive | pigz -0 -p largenumber > mydir.tar.gz
>
> Example - tar cf - patha | pigz -0 -p 32 > patha.tar.gz

This is probably faster than the methods suggested in the post as -p is the number of processes one can run. In my personal experience setting a very large value doesnt hurt performance if the directory to be archived consists of a large number of small files. Else the default value considered is 8. For large files, my recommendation would be to set this value as the total number of threads supported on the system.

Example setting a value of p = 32 in case of a 32 CPU machine helps.

0 is meant for the fastest pigz compression as it doesnt compress the archive and rather is focussed on speed. Default value is 6 for compression.

Comment: Why would you use pigz at all if you weren't planning to compress the archive?